# Changing the RememberMe token - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying add a new value to the RememberMe token.

My system will block the user in case of idle time.

I tried to use this

```
$token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
$token->setAttribute('UserBlocked',TRUE);
```

But when I close the browser and open the page again, the attribute is dissapear and just the RememberMe persist.

How can change the specific RememberMe token and persist that information?

For a while I'm creating a cookie that holds the information at the same time of the RememberMe, but I think that is not a good solution, isn't?

Thank you guys!

Comment: What do you mean by "block" the user? Log him out?

Comment: Like the windows, when you press Windows + L, the system locks you and you need to re-insert the password, otherwise you will be logged but locked.